# Substring search with max 1's in a binary sequence

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

##### Problem

The task is to find a substring from the given binary string with highest score. The substring should be at least of given min length.

`score = number of 1s / substring length` where score can range from 0 to 1.

```
Inputs:
1. min length of substring
2. binary sequence

Outputs:
1. index of first char of substring
2. index of last char of substring
```

###### Example 1:

```
input
-----
5
01010101111100

output
------
7
11

explanation
-----------
1. start with minimum window = 5
2. start_ind = 0, end_index = 4, score = 2/5 (0.4)
3. start_ind = 1, end_index = 5, score = 3/5 (0.6)
4. and so on...
5. start_ind = 7, end_index = 11, score = 5/5 (1) [max possible]
```

###### Example 2:

```
input
-----
5
10110011100

output
------
2
8

explanation
-----------
1. while calculating all scores for windows 5 to len(sequence)
2. max score occurs in the case: start_ind=2, end_ind=8, score=5/7 (0.7143) [max possible]
```

###### Example 3:

```
input
-----
4
00110011100

output
------
5
8
```

##### What I attempted

The only technique i could come up with was a brute force technique, with nested for loops

```
for window_size in (min to max)
  for ind 0 to end
    calculate score
    save max score
```

Can someone suggest a better algorithm to solve this problem?

Comment: Is it subsequence  or subarray?

Comment: @nice_dev Yes, you are right, I mean subarray or substring, contiguous subset, will correct it in the question also, Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @nice_dev, Thanks to you, I have replaced all mentions of subsequence to substring, in the question

Comment: Your question is still ambiguous. It seems that the answer will always be the entire string having max number of `1` with also satisfying the `min length` constraint.

Comment: Is `number of 1s / substring length` a float division?

Comment: @nice_dev I think the same too. Using this property, an algorithm can be devised. I just hope there are no counter example to this point.

Comment: @AKSingh I presume there are. Waiting for OP to elaborate on this with more examples.

Comment: The best subarray will always start with a 1, and end with a 1. Which means that you don't have to consider every possible start index from 0 to `length - window_size`. You only need to consider the first 1 of each block of 1's as the start, and only the last 1 of each block as the end. So in your second example, there are only three possible starting positions, and only one possible end position. The exception to the rule (that the best subarray starts and ends with a 1) is a minimum-length subarray. The minimum length subarrays need to be checked separately using a simple sliding window.

Comment: @nice_dev, the division is a float division.

Comment: @user3386109, this is an excellent approach, can you submit this as an answer?

Comment: @HamzaZubair Ok, can you put an explanation in your post for the sample testcases taking that float division into consideration?

Comment: @user3386109 I agree the best subarray will always start with a 1 (apart from the case where the first 1 is so much at the end that you will need to take the last N values to respect the minimum length requirement). But are you sure it will also _end_ with a 1? Suppose you have a sequence 1111001 with minimum length 5

Comment: @gimix It doesn't have to start with 1 either. Consider your own example, but in reverse (1001111)

Comment: My idea for the reversed example was, the first substring starting with 1 has 3 out of 5, while the second one is too much at the end, so we'll have take the last five values, and get 4 out of 5. But probably we should say it must start _or_ end with a 1 (or both)

Comment: @gimix The last two sentences in my comment cover your example. For 1111001, the best subarray is 11110, which is a minimum-length subarray. Minimum-length subarrays are the exception, and must be handled separately.

Comment: @HamzaZubair That comment is just a hint to help you start thinking about the problem. There's a lot more to it, and in fact I don't have a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few observations to make before we start talking about an algorithm- some of these observations already have been pointed out in the comments.

---

**Maths**

Take the minimum length to be `M`, the length of the entire string to be `L`, and a substring from the `i`th char to the `j`th char (inclusive-exclusive) to be `S[i:j]`.

All optimal substrings will satisfy at least one of two conditions:

- It is exactly `M` characters in length
- It starts and ends with a `1` character

The reason for the latter being if it were longer than `M` characters and started/ended with a `0`, we could just drop that `0` resulting in a higher ratio.

In the same spirit (again, for the 2nd case), there exists an optimal substring which is not preceded by a `1`. Otherwise, if it were, we could include that `1`, resulting in an equal or higher ratio. The same logic applies to the end of `S` and a following `1`.

Building on the above- such a substring being preceded or followed by another `1` will NOT be optimal, unless the substring contains no `0`s. In the case where it doesn't contain `0`s, there will exist an optimal substring of length `M` as well anyways.

Again, that all only applies to the length greater than `M` case substrings.

Finally, there exists an optimal substring that has length at least `M` (by definition), and at most `2 * M - 1`.  If an optimal substring had length `K`, we could split it into two substrings of length `floor(K/2)` and `ceil(K/2)` - `S[i:i+floor(K/2)]` and `S[i+floor(K/2):i+K]`. If the substring has the score (ratio) `R`, and its halves `R0` and `R1`, we would have one of two scenarios:

- `R = R0 = R1`, meaning we could pick either half and get the same score as the combined substring, giving us a shorter substring.

  - If this substring has length less than `2 * M`, we are done- we have an optimal substring of length `[M, 2*M)`.
  - Otherwise, recurse on the new substring.
- `R0 != R1`, so (without loss of generality) `R0 < R < R1`, meaning the combined substring would not be optimal in the first place.

Note that I say "there exists an optimal" as opposed to "**the** optimal". This is because there may be multiple optimal solutions, and the observations above may refer to different instances.

---

**Algorithm**

You could search every window size `[M, 2*M)` at every offset, which would already be better than a full search for small `M`.  You can also try a two-phase approach:

1. search every `M` sized window, find the max score
2. search from the beginning of every run of `1`s forward through a special list of ends of runs of `1`s, implicitly skipping over `0`s and irrelevant `1`s, breaking when out of the `[M, 2 * M)` bound.

For random data, I only expect this to save a small factor- skipping 15/16 of the windows (ignoring the added overhead). For less-random data, you could potentially see huge benefits, particularly if there's LOTS of LARGE runs of `1`s and `0`s.

The biggest speedup you'll be able to do (besides limiting the window max to `2 * M`) is computing a cumulative sum of the bit array. This lets you query "how many `1`s were seen up to this point". You can then take the difference of two elements in this array to query "how many `1`s occurred between these offsets" in constant time. This allows for very quick calculation of the score.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 pointer method, starting from both left-most and right-most ends. then adjust them searching for highest score.
We can add some cache to optimize time.

Example: (Python)

```py
binary="01010101111100"
length=5


def get_score(binary,left,right):
    ones=0
    for i in range(left,right+1):
        if binary[i]=="1":
            ones+=1
    score= ones/(right-left+1)
    return score
    
cache={}
def get_sub(binary,length,left,right):
    if (left,right) in cache:
        return cache[(left,right)]
    table=[0,set()]
    if right-left+1<length:
        pass
    else:
        scores=[[get_score(binary,left,right),set([(left,right)])],
                get_sub(binary,length,left+1,right),
                get_sub(binary,length,left,right-1),
                get_sub(binary,length,left+1,right-1)]
        for s in scores:
            if s[0]>table[0]:
                table[0]=s[0]
                table[1]=s[1]
            elif s[0]==table[0]:
                for e in s[1]:
                    table[1].add(e)
    cache[(left,right)]=table
    return table

result=get_sub(binary,length,0,len(binary)-1)

print("Score: %f"%result[0])
print("Index: %s"%result[1])
```

Output

```
Score: 1
Index: {(7, 11)}
```